# make a portion of a UIView become transparent

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiview

I have a UIView w/c I returned as view in my viewForHeaderInSection. Now, I want to make a small transparent square on the lower right of the view so the cells will be seen through. How can I achieve something like this? Do I need to use this CGContextSetBlendMode? can anyone shed light on this.

Comment: You could make it all transparent and add a uiimageview as a background with a png that has that portion transparent.

Comment: Can you add a blueprint from the result? It's hard to visualize.

Answer (score 0):

The view are inserted as subviews inside of SwitchViewController.view. So, they will always appear above the SwitchViewControllers view. The other view is removed, Only one view will be appeared at 1 time

e.g. Here

```
[yellowViewController.view removeFromSuperview];
[self.view insertSubview:blueViewController.view atIndex:0];
```

view appears behind its subview by default, and

```
insertSubview:atIndex:
```

can't place it behind the view itself, as a view is not contained in the list of its own subviews.

Comment: let me know if this code work..I was having the same prob which I have solved through stack only

Answer (score 0):

Here is a UIView subclass solution. In order for this to work you must leave the superviews backgroundColor property as nil witch is the default value. If this UIView-subclass is in the storyboard then make sure you set the background color to "Clear color" in the attributes inspector.

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    UIColor *blackBackgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:1];
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(ctx, blackBackgroundColor.CGColor);
    CGContextFillRect(ctx, rect);
    CGRect transparentPart = CGRectMake(10, 10, 120, 80);
    CGContextClearRect(ctx, transparentPart);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CALayer *layer = [[CALayer alloc] init];
[layer setFrame:yourBoundsInView];

[[yourView layer] setMask:layer];
```

or override the drawRect method and add the below lines of code at the end

```
UIBezierPath *seeThrough = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:seeThroughRect];
[[UIColor colorWithWhite:1 alpha:0] set];
[seeThrough fillWithBlendMode:kCGBlendModeSourceIn alpha:1];
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply mask for your View.

Tutorial: https://medium.com/@peteliev/layer-masking-for-beginners-c18a0a10743

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)